# tex4ht produces corrupted output when using \Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}

Tags: tex4ht, adjustbox

In the tex4ht configuration file, I have these 2 lines:

```
    \Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
    \Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class="math";align="absmiddle"}
```

These have been the .cfg for 5 years or more. No problem. These are used to tell tex4ht to convert inline math to images, else it will not. So these 2 lines are very basic and must be there all the time.

I just found out now, for some reason, when I use `adjustbox`, that the output is all corrupted on the HTML page. It turned out that removing the above 2 lines from the .cfg file, then the output becomes OK.

I have no idea why these 2 lines affect `adjustbox` or cause tex4ht to do this.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.8\textwidth,fbox=0.1pt,margin=2pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true]
  This is just some text
     which is verbatim using listing
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Here is MWE  `nma.cfg` file which should be in the same folder as the .tex file

```
\Preamble{ext=htm,charset="utf-8",p-width,pic-align}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="utf-8"/>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}

\begin{document}
\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}
\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class="math";align="absmiddle"} 
\EndPreamble
```

Compile with `htlatex  foo7_1.tex "nma.cfg,htm"`

The HTML page is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When removing the .cfg file, and compiling using `htlatex  foo7_1.tex "htm"` the output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For somereason, tex4ht thought `adjustbox` content was math and tried to make it an image?  Removing `adjustbox` and keeping the .cfg also solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true]
  This is just some text
     which is verbatim using listing
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

Compiling using `htlatex  foo7_1.tex "nma.cfg,htm"` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the question is: Can one use keep the .cfg as is, and using `adjustbox` with tex4ht?

This problem happens on TL 2015 and TL 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tex4ht` doesn't think that `adjustbox` uses math mode. `adjustbox` uses math mode internally, at least with your options. there is no configuration for `adjustbox` for `tex4ht`. some basic configuration, which just resets `adjustbox` environment and prints some basic HTML structure which can be styled using CSS, may look like this:

```
% adjustbox.4ht
\renewenvironment{adjustbox}[1]{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{adjustbox}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="adjustbox">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\endinput
```

the resulting HTML:

```html
  <div class="adjustbox"> <!--l. 6-->
   <div class="lstlisting" id="listing-1"><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">This</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">is</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">just</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">some</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">text</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><br /><span class="label"><a 
 id="x1-3r2"></a></span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">which</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">is</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">verbatim</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">using</span><span 
class="cmtt-12"> </span><span 
class="cmtt-12">listing</span>
   </div>
   </div>
```

[image]