# problem with Vertical alignment of text and images in long table when using tex4ht

Tags: graphics, longtable, tex4ht

With the help of experts in [Yet another images in tables question alignment. Want text to start at top of cell. Not cetered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489102/yet-another-images-in-tables-question-alignment-want-text-to-start-at-top-of-ce) I can now get text to show in correct place with images in a long table, when using `lualatex`.

But the same solution does not work when I compile to HTML using make4ht. So this question is asking what to do to make the result show the same in HTML as in PDF.  Here is a MWE. The issue seems to be that `valign=t` from `adjustbox` has no effect in tex4ht as it does in pdf.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}%loads graphicx
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1in}|p{3in}|p{1in}|}\hline 
Test A&\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in,valign=t]{example-image-a}&TestB\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex foo4.tex` gives expected output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compiling the same file with `make4ht foo4.tex` gives this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want the text to be at the top, like it shows in PDF.

Since clearly `valign=t` does not work in tex4ht, what other options are there to do the same in tex4ht? How to best resolve this issue? Do I need some CSS special configuration?

The HTML code generated is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta  charset="iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo4.css" /> 
<meta name="src" content="foo4.tex" /> 
</head><body 
>
<a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a>   <!--l. 8--><div class="longtable"> <table id="TBL-1" class="longtable" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  
><colgroup id="TBL-1-1g"><col 
id="TBL-1-1" /></colgroup><colgroup id="TBL-1-2g"><col 
id="TBL-1-2" /></colgroup><colgroup id="TBL-1-3g"><col 
id="TBL-1-3" /></colgroup>
<tr 
class="hline"><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td></tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-1-"><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-1-1"  
class="td11">
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >Test A          </p></td><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-1-2"  
class="td11">
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" ><img 
src="example-image-a.png" alt="PIC"  
width="216" height="162"  />                                                  </p></td><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-1-3"  
class="td11">
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >TestB           </p></td>
</tr><tr 
class="hline"><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td><td><hr /></td></tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-2-"><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-2-1"  
class="td11">            </td>
</tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-3-"><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-3-1"  
class="td11">            </td>
</tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-4-"><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-4-1"  
class="td11">
<!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" >            </p></td>
</tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-5-"><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-5-1"  
class="td11">
<!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" >            </p></td>
</tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-6-"><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-6-1"  
class="td11">              </td><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-6-2"  
class="td11">                                         </td><td  style="white-space:normal; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-6-3"  
class="td11"></td></tr>
   </table></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

**Update**

I found that if I manually edit the HTML and replace

```
 <tr  style="vertical-align:baseline;"
```

With

```
  <tr   style="vertical-align: top;"
```

Then it works!

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, I am not able to figure out the correct CSS to add to my .cfg in order to tell tex4ht to use this style for `tr`.  So I just need to figure this part out.

I've added

```
  \Css{tr {vertical-align:top;}}
```

to my .cfg, but it has no effect. The generated HTML still shows `<tr  style="vertical-align:baseline;"`. So I have no idea now how to overwrite this and do not know where tex4ht sets `vertical-align:baseline` to change it!

This is very complicated business modifying CSS style in tex4ht since there are so many classes and I am never sure which one to modify.

TL 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we need to get rid of the default  `vertical-align` inserted in the `style` attribute of  all table rows, and then insert the correct vertical alignment for the current row in the CSS.

We can patch the commands `adjustbox` uses for the vertical alignment of the rows. We will use these to insert the necessary CSS code. The file `adjustbox.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignTop}{1}
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignMiddle}{1}
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignCenter}{1}
\NewConfigure{AdjustboxValignBottom}{1}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@t{\a:AdjustboxValignTop}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@t{\a:AdjustboxValignTop}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@T{\a:AdjustboxValignTop}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@M{\a:AdjustboxValignMiddle}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@m{\a:AdjustboxValignMiddle}
\pend:defI\adjbox@valign@c{\a:AdjustboxValignCenter}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@b{\a:AdjustboxValignBottom}
\pend:def\adjbox@valign@B{\a:AdjustboxValignBottom}
\Hinput{adjustbox}
```

The CSS instructions can be inserted in the `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{halignTR}{}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignTop}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:top;}}}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignMiddle}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:middle;}}}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignCenter}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:middle;}}}
\Configure{AdjustboxValignBottom}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:bottom;}}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{halignTR}{}` disables insertion of the `style` attribute for `<tr>` elements. The

```
\Configure{AdjustboxValignTop}{\Css{\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:top;}}}
```

and variants of this configuration are used for the CSS declaration. `\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-` contains `id` of the current row.

The following sample:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490873/2891
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}%loads graphicx
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{1in}|p{3in}|p{1in}|}\hline 
Test A&\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in,valign=t]{example-image-a}&TestB\\\hline
test d & \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}& test f\\\hline
test d & \includegraphics[width=3in,valign=b]{example-image-a}& test f\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

produces a following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I want to try it. But it is not clear where should I copy the file `adjustbox.4ht` that you show above to? which folder? should it go to `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/` ? or somewhere else? Will this file be included in official source code so next time I update it be there? I did `kpsewhich adjustbox.4ht` but there was no current file with this name now there. So I assume this is new file.

Comment: ps. I also need to merge/add to `adjustbox.4ht`  the content of  your other fix as shown here  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316979/tex4ht-produces-corrupted-output-when-using-configure-picmath-endpicmath  but not sure if it should go above or below what you have here. I am actually a  little confused now about this file..

Comment: fyi. It works. I put your `adjustbox.4ht` for now in my `$HOME` folder and edits my .cfg with your code. All is working.

Comment: I hope this file `adjustbox.4ht` will be in the official release in TL as your fixes above are very important. I'll keep this file in my HOME folder for now.Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Nasser ah, I totally forgot about my old answer. I have some code also for your `\includegraphics` problem, so I will put it to the sources once everything works

Comment: I think the .4ht is not being seen by make4ht. I get these errors now when I compile another file `(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
l.108 --- TeX4ht warning --- \Configure{AdjustboxValignTop}? ---
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \#TBL-\TableNo -\HRow
                      -{vertical-align:top;}
l.108 ...\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-{vertical-align:top;}}                                                  }? X`
Where should I copy the `adjustbox.4ht` file you show above? Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser try something like `~/texmf/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.4ht`